# Split Action Bar not working

Tags: android, xml

i have been looking for solutions for hours. i'm trying to split my action bar but it keeps stacking up in the top-right corner.
this is my menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:balloonberry="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    balloonberry:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_location_found"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found"
    android:title="@string/action_location_found"
    balloonberry:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_refresh"
    balloonberry:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    balloonberry:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="@string/action_check_updates"
    balloonberry:showAsAction="always"/>

    </menu>
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zapp.exampleproject1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"></uses-sdk>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
              android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow`" />

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

any solutions???? (i'm using a android 4.3 phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `appcompat-v7`, nor the native action bar on Android 5.0+, support the split action bar. That pattern was officially discontinued as part of the Material Design overhaul. If you want that capability, you will need to put your own `Toolbar` at the bottom of your activity.